# How to replace " " with %20 in android

Tags: java, android, url, androidhttpclient

I am doing a service call functionality in android.
In the following URL(String) I need to replace `" "`(space) with `%20`

http://dli.ircms.in/complaint.php?complaintno=sarojini nagar/06022014/4

**I tried**

```
URl.replace(" ", "%20")
URl.replaceAll(" ", "%20")
URL sourceUrl = new URL(url);
url = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

but it is not changing I do not know why.

Please help me..

Answer (score 4):

With the `URLDecoder` one, it doesn't work because you have to **encode**, not decode:

```
url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

For other examples you posted, you need to reassign the string:

```
url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

As Petter pointed out, `URLEncoder.encode` will add `+` instead of `%20`. This is how URLEncoder works, but you can use

```
url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8").replace("+","%20");
```

to make it work as you want.

Another option is to use the `Uri` class:

```
String url = "http://dli.ircms.in/complaint.php";
url = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("complaintno","sarojini nagar/06022014/4").build().toString();
```

Result:

```
http://dli.ircms.in/complaint.php?complaintno=sarojini%20nagar%2F06022014%2F4
```

Comment: Yes I reassigned it. but not changing.

Comment: @user2085965 That's impossible. Please post the updated code.

Comment: @user2085965 Try it now, it works for me (tested on an android device)

Answer (score 2):

you should use URLEncoder:

```
String url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the url in form of a string, a string is immutable so you have to assign the replaced string to a new one.

```
String url = theOriginalUrlString.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

The replacement is reflected in the new string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String url = "http://test.com/this is a test";
System.out.println(url);
url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
System.out.println(url);
```

or:

```
String url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Should be encode instead of decode.